# Swap position of two strings in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

The current date format of a page is

```
maart 2 2015
```

The HTML created for this is:

```
<span class="entry-time">
    <span class="updated" style="display:none;">2015-03-06T09:24:26+00:00</span>
    <time class="published" datetime="2015-03-02T16:58:01+00:00">maart 2 2015</time>
</span>
```

What I want to do is swtich the places of maart and 2 so that the string reads "2 maart 2015".

Is this possible in jquery?

Comment: A better approach is probably to configure the date format in your server-side app.

Comment: You would be better off using a date object and formatting it as needed, there are libraries online that help in doing this. Alternatively, replace the entire InnerHTML with a formatted string from the datetime attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a problem at all. For example this line would do the job:

```
var splitted = $(".published").html().split(" ");
$(".published").html(splitted[1] + " " + splitted[0] + " " + splitted[2]);
```

What we do here is using the first `.html` to give all the elements with the class `.published` (make sure you don't have unwanted "published" elements) a new inner html data. We provide a string which is the new text in the tag. 
We split the string by space and have a array with three elements (maart, 2, 2015). Now we simply have to reverse the order (1, 0, 2) and we're done.

Comment: This worked for me, but now I get this result as a string: "2maart2015"

Comment: @Mdew: just add `+ " " +` : a space between the splitted values.

Comment: @mdew I'm sorry. Mouser is right. I've forgotten to add the space. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Cheers guys! Great help

Comment: @mdew would you mind accepting my answer as correct? :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you just need to make some treatment using the native split() method:

```
var str = "maart 2 2015";
var result = str.split(" ");
```

Gives :

```
maart,2,2015
```

Then you just need to recreate a new string from this array in the order of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is in wordpress?
If it is, go to settings -> general and set your timezone if it is not correct.
Then below you can change the format by selecting one or by creating one
http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time

it should then go as you wan't if the theme is developed in a good way

Answer (score 0):

You can separate it into an array by spaces then switch the position of the words like so:

```
var array = $(".published").text().split(" ");
$(".published").text(array[1]+" "+array[0]+" "+array[2])
```

Or you can just change the text:

```
$(".published").text("2 maart 2015")
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is the script I used eventually:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".published").html(
        $(".published").html().split(" ")[1] + " " + 
        $(".published").html().split(" ")[0] + " " +
        $(".published").html( ).split(" ")[2]
    );
});
</script>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Here a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qr1zzp3b/

```
var months = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
    "October", "November", "December");

    var d = new Date();
    var date = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    console.log(date + " " + months[month] 
    + " " + year);
```

Comment: This provides a current date. It does not reformat the existing string in the element.

Comment: Yeah I thought that is what op wanted. The start of the question is ambiguous: "The current date format of a page is"